# C++ Builder заполнение Tlistview данными из массива

Tags: c++builder, vcl

Задача следующая - Используя представленный ниже код реализовать вывод данных из массива в компонент ListView.

```
void Tmainform::CustomerView()
{
   customer_lv->Items->BeginUpdate();
   customer_lv->Items->Clear();

   for(int i = 0; i < cust_count; i++)
   {
      TListItem* item = customer_lv->Items->Add();
      item->Caption    = customers[i].name;
      item->ImageIndex = 1;// индекс иконки
      item->Data       = (void*)i;// индекс массива
      item->SubItems->Add(customers[i].address);
      …
   }
   customer_lv->Items->EndUpdate();
}.
```